# What's the average euclidian distance between two points on a unit n-sphere?

Tags: probability, spheres

Suppose we randomly place 2 points the 100-dimensional unit sphere. So we have
$$x_1, x_2\in \mathbb{R}^{100}\quad\text{ and }\quad|x_1|=|x_2|=1$$

What's the expected value of the euclidian distance between them?
$$E[|x_1 - x_2|]=\ ?$$
From just eyeballing some data, the answer looks like $\approx1.2$

And what about in general? So for 2 points on an n-dimensional sphere?

Comment: Anybody have time to do a 100 dimensional integral?

Comment: See [The Sphere Game in n Dimensions](http://faculty.madisoncollege.edu/alehnen/sphere/hypers.htm).

Comment: The link is now broken. Can you provide a new link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eyeballing it, choose coordinates so that one point is at $\theta=0$. Then $\theta$ is the only relevant angular variable, and the length of the chord is $2\sin{(\theta/2)}$ so the integral should reduce to
$$ \frac{\int_0^{\pi} 2\sin{(\theta/2)} \sin^{n-1}{\theta} \, d\theta }{ \int_0^{\pi} \sin^{n-1}{\theta} \, d\theta} = \frac{2\Gamma(n)\Gamma((n+1)/2)}{\Gamma(n/2)\Gamma(n+1/2)} = \frac{2^n [\Gamma((n+1)/2)]^2}{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(n+1/2)} $$
using various trigonometric and Gamma identities. For $n=100$, this gives a large fraction that is approximately $1.412$.

Comment: Thanks. After looking closely at my data points, I noticed they're all positive points. I figure that's where their mean distances look less than 1.4. Is there any easy modification to that equation for points with only positive coordinates?

Comment: Which is squared?  $(n+1)/2$ or its gamma function?

Comment: Unfortunately you lose the symmetry, so probably have to do the whole horrific $2n$-dimensional integral.

Comment: See comment and link from dxiv above.